# Returning an object in .each iteration - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

I have an object called `Category` which uses a method to iterate over an array of products (`Product`) and return an instance which meets the `this.name === query` condition:

```
function Category(products){
  this.products = products; 
  this.findProductByName = function(query){
    $(this.products).each(function(){
      return this.name === query; 
    }
  }
}
```

My `Product` (just in case):

```
function Product(name){
  this.name = name;
}
```

I then create an instance of `Category` with products:

```
var $someCategory = new Category(
   [
      new Product('foo'),
      new Product('bar')
   ]
)`
```

and when I call:

```
$someCategory.findProductByName('foo'); // 'undefined'
```

even though:

```
...
this.findProductByName = function(query){
  $(this.products).each(function(){
    console.log(this.name === query); // returns 'true'
  }
}
...
```

What do I do to return an object when `this.name === query` is met?

Comment: The `$.each()` mechanism ignores the returned values (mostly). What is it that you expect it to do?

Comment: use [].filter() and [].map() instead of each()

Comment: @Pointy return the correct `Product` instance when the conditional is met, so that I can search for products within `$someCategory` by name. What do you mean by "ignores the returned values"?

Comment: The `return` from *inside* the `$.each()` callback only returns from that function; it doesn't return from your `findProductByName` function.

Comment: @Pointy ahhhhhhh, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a traditional loop with a return (or map/reduce) to have your function return the matched result. The each function performs an operation on each element in the array, it, won't perform filtering, and ignores the returned value.

Try this:

```
this.findProductByName = function(query) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
    if (this.products[i].name === query)
    {
      return this.products[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Also FYI, It's normal to pass arguments into the `each()` function which identify the current element being iterated over when using  This helps eliminate the scope issue for 'this'

```
$(this.products).each(function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Question: so why use `each` at all when the `for loop` already handles the iteration and returns vals?

Comment: It's syntactic niceness for when you explicitly want to perform an operation on each item in the array, i.e. adding a prefix to the name property:  
  $(this.products).each(function(i,el){el.name = 'My ' + el.name;});

Comment: Also some people just love jquery over native javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use jQuery? Can you instead use the array filter method...

```
function Category(products){
  this.products = products; 
  this.findProductByName = function(query){
    return this.products.filter(function(item){
      return item.name === query; 
    });
  };
}
```